# Deleting connection strings in a dataset

Tags: ado.net, visual-studio-2005

When I'm viewing the connection string options in the properties view of a TableAdapter, I get a list of options for connection strings. Our project has evolved in such a way that many of these options refer to databases that no longer exist on the server. Is there a way to delete these?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in the "configuration/connectionStrings" xpath of your dll's app.config file.